# Check if collection exists in mongodb using MongoDB\Driver in PHP 7.1.6

Tags: php, mongodb

I have searched for the answer without any results. I need to check if a Collection exists in my mongodatbase using MongoDB\Driver in PHP 7.1.6. Does anyone know how to do it? thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have done this method to verify if there exist a collection must pass the name, you will return 0 if it does not exist and 1 if it exists

```
public function verifyCollection($name){

  $bd = $this->conexion->mongo(); 
  $data = $bd->listCollections([
   'filter' => [
       'name' => $name,
    ], 
 ]);

$exist = 0;
  foreach ($data as $collectionInfo) {
    $exist = 1;
   }

    return $exist;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `db.getCollectionNames()` and then test for existence of the collection you seek with `indexOf()`  e.g.

```
 idx = db.getCollectionNames().indexOf("myColl");
```

If idx = -1, then `myColl` does NOT exist.   The equiv in perl would be

```
my @collections = $database->collection_names;
```

Then you can use smartmatch or grep or whatever you like to scan the collections list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `listCollections()` just remember it returns an **object** and not an array.
In the below code $collectionNames is an array of just the names.

```
$collections = $database->listCollections();
$collectionNames = [];
foreach ($collections as $collection) {
  $collectionNames[] = $collection->getName();
}
```

Then check it like this:

```
$exists = in_array('some_collection', $collectionNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Basically you use `listCollections()` function, but it was not easy to figure out how to use it correctly in php-extension (thanks to @John56 for his answer in this thread). `$manager` is `MongoDB\Driver\Manager` class. Hope it helps you to save some time :)

```
$command = new Command(['listCollections' => 1, 'filter' => ['name' => 'collection-name']]);
$result = $manager->executeCommand('db-name', $command)->toArray();
if (false == empty($result) { whatever ...}
```

Answer (score -1):

First create your mongo object here **$mongodb_object**
then

```
$collections = $mongodb_object->getCollectionNames();
```

The collections variable contains all the collection names as array
Return array example is given below

```
[0] => collection_name1
[1] => collection_name2
[2] => collection_name3
```